# Upgraded to MVC 3:  CS0103: The name 'View' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have just updated to ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2.

The sample app I am working on now produces the following error, whenever a cshtml view is rendered:

CS0103: The name 'View' does not exist in the current context

It fails on the line:

```
@{
   View.Title = "MyView";
}
```

... and fails anywhere else it encounters View in the code on the Razor file.

I have copied the web.config from a new apps View folder to my sample app, but the problem persists.

A brand new application runs without problems.

I have also rebuilt the solution, run Clean Solution.  No joy.

I haven't worked on the sample for a few days. So it might be an issue that has nothing to do with RC2...

Comment: Have checked the references, they seem to be the same file version.  EG: System.Web.Mvc File Version: 3.11209.0 for both my sample app, developed using RC1 and a new app created using RC2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's been renamed 'ViewBag'. You can read more about the changes from RC1 -> RC2 [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I had overlooked that bit of the Scott Guthrie blog post.  Don't know why you think it is strange - it is fine to have display logic in the views.  Loads of samples use that.  I think ViewBag is a horrible name, but it is more descriptive than just plain View.

Comment: @awrigley sure it's fine to use display logic in the view, but the ViewBag is intended to be a collection of properties that are typically set in the controller to be used in the view... I'm sure you have a valid use case, but I failt to see why you would want to set data in the ViewBag inside the view, I would expect only 'reading' from it.

Comment: "ViewBag" is now going to be my go-to name to call people I don't like.

Comment: @awrigley finally revisited this question; the reason this is called in the view is to communicate information (the view Title in this case) back to the 'Layout' view. Which is legitimate of course. Sorry for the confusion I may have caused

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but I just tried to guess what to use now, I ended up using:

```
@Page.Title = "The title"
```

and it worked, though I'm not sure what is the "best practice" now

Also, I thought that the ViewBag is what used to be ViewModel, not just View

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this in case anyone else comes across it. Another possible cause is that your Layout was not found. I deployed to IIS and (after commenting out the offending line) found that the Layout hadn't been copied during web deploy. In my case, it was because the layout's Build Action had been changed from Content to None.

EDIT: In fact, I had MVC 3 RC installed. The above was just a different symptom. The deployment machine had RTM which exposed the problem. As awrigley says, it's called ViewBag now.

Comment: thanks, but the problem in my case was the renaming of the property to ViewBag.